Spark SQL 3.5.1 How to consume MQTT data in real time, is there any existing library? Do I need a custom data source? How to customize it?
I am using Spark SQL 3.5.1 to consume MQTT live data, and the latest version uses DataSet unbounded tables to process live data, but there is no up-to-date tutorial in the documentation. How do I consume MQTT data and implement sliding window calculations? Do I need to implement the data source manually? How to do that? Can you write data from a Rest interface to a live data stream and then compute it? Please help me. Thank you.
I expect the following to happen
val ds = sparkSession.readStream()
               .format("com.smart.iot.spark.dataSource.MQTTDataSourceProvider")
               .option("username","")
               .option("password","")
               .load("url");

The data produced by MQTT can be written to Spark in real time for sliding mean calculation
